# Spring Boot - Redis persistence token

Tags: spring-security, redis, spring-boot

I have a project that uses this scheme:

- Spring Boot
- Spring Security
- Redis

Everything works fine except the session time.
I want to keep the token in Redis permanent. The token must have no expiration how should I do?
This and configuration of my HttpSessionConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class HttpSessionConfig {

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
            return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }   
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was suggested by Mr Rwinch to use this command:

```
EnableRedisHttpSession (MaxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = Integer.MAX_VALUE)
```

In this way, the session will expire in 68 years :)